# Does anyone know how to reduce the font size of numbers in vennDiagram plot?

Tags: r, fonts, venn-diagram

I couldn't find a way to reduce the font size of the numbers inside the venn diagram plot. Here are the commands that i have used to produce the plot.

```
library("limma")
tissue_ven <- vennCounts(tissue_all)
vennDiagram(tissue_ven, names = c("INTERNODE", "LEAF", "ROOT", "SILIQUE", "SEEDLING"), cex = 1, lwd = 1, circle.col= " blue", counts.col="red")
```

Thanks in advance for help.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could set `cex` argument to `0.5` for example, but this will change size of all text elements. I don't see a way to change specific text elements separately without customizing `vennDiagram` function itself

Answer (score 1):

Use the cex=c() to change the sizes corresponding to each of the names

names = c("INTERNODE", "LEAF", "ROOT", "SILIQUE", "SEEDLING"), cex=c(1,5,4,2,1), lwd = 1.....